# merge multiple TRUE/FALSE columns into one

Tags: r

I want to find a way to coerce all the logical columns into a single column with the column titles as factors.

Here is an example:

```
  Eviction.ID  Non.Payment Breach Nuisance Illegal.Use
1     M162268        TRUE  FALSE    FALSE       FALSE
2     M161957       FALSE  FALSE     TRUE       FALSE
3     M162256        TRUE  FALSE    FALSE       FALSE
4     M162135       FALSE   TRUE    FALSE       FALSE
5     M161901       FALSE  FALSE     TRUE       FALSE
6     M162428       FALSE  FALSE    FALSE        TRUE
```

Desired Output:

```
Eviction.ID             Reason 
1     M162268       Non.Payment 
2     M161957          Nuisance 
3     M162256       Non.Payment 
4     M162135            Breach 
5     M161901          Nuisance 
6     M162428       Illegal.Use
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `max.col` to get the index of the `max` value (here it is TRUE) in each row, get the corresponding column names based on that index and `cbind` with the first column.

```
cbind(df1[1], Reason= names(df1)[max.col(df1[-1], "first")+1])
#  Eviction.ID      Reason
#1     M162268 Non.Payment
#2     M161957    Nuisance
#3     M162256 Non.Payment
#4     M162135      Breach
#5     M161901    Nuisance
#6     M162428 Illegal.Use
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape the data from wide to long, then it becomes a standard subsetting operation

```
library(reshape2)

## melt from wide to long
df <- melt(df, "Eviction.ID", variable.name = "Reason")

## subset on TRUE values/rows, and keep the columns of interest
df[df$value == TRUE, c("Eviction.ID", "Reason")]
#    Eviction.ID      Reason
# 1      M162268 Non.Payment
# 3      M162256 Non.Payment
# 10     M162135      Breach
# 14     M161957    Nuisance
# 17     M161901    Nuisance
# 24     M162428 Illegal.Use
```