# Pivot/merge some columns in a dataset while keeping remaining columns

Tags: r, pivot, pivot-table, tidyr

I have a dataset that resembles this (but with more columns):

```
table <- "year site square triangle circle
1  2019    A 3 9 5
2  2019    A 5 NA 34
3  2019    B 0 0 69
4  2019    B NA 111 2
5  2020    C 0 45 3
6  2020    C 29 0 NA 
7  2020    D NA 0 1
8  2021    D 3 NA 4
9  2021    D 158 5 0
10 2021    D 2 9 0"

df <- read.table(text=table, header = TRUE)
df
```

I want to pivot a portion of the the table so that it resembles this:

```
   year site type count
1  2019    A square   3
2  2019    A triangle 9
3  2019    A circle   5
4  2019    A square   5
5  2019    A triangle NA
6  2019    A circle   34
7  2019    B square   0
8  2019    B triangle 0 
9  2019    B circle  60
```

(and so on)

I've tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271884/merge-multiple-true-false-columns-while-keeping-remaining-columns-in-a-dataframe), but this does not deal with counts so I lose that value when I use these solutions.

For example, the below code leaves me with NAs in each column and I lose the count values

```
df2 <- df[1:2]
df2$type <- apply(df[3:5], 1, function(k) names(df[3:5])[k])
df2

   year site             type
1  2019    A   circle, NA, NA
2  2019    A       NA, NA, NA
3  2019    B               NA
4  2019    B NA, NA, triangle
5  2020    C       NA, circle
6  2020    C           NA, NA
7  2020    D       NA, square
8  2021    D   circle, NA, NA
9  2021    D           NA, NA
10 2021    D     triangle, NA
```

I've also tried using `tidyr` `gather()` package, but this won't allow me to keep multiple columns.

```
library(tidyr)
df3 <- gather(df, year, site, `square`:`circle`)
head(df3)

    year site
1 square    3
2 square    5
3 square    0
4 square   NA
5 square    0
6 square   29
```

My only idea is to make a new column of unique numbers (1-X) in my dataframe, use that with `gather()`, then merge the original dataframe and the new dataframe by that unique ID, then remove the unwanted columns. This would work, but I'm wondering if there's a better, cleaner solution?

Comment: jl748795, Stack's tag-recommendation engine is at best "imperfect", please pay attention to the tags it suggests and be a little more critical of them: [tag:rstudio] (since removed) is purely for questions about the IDE itself, not the R language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `tidyr::pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyr)

tidyr::pivot_longer(df, -c(year, site))
#> # A tibble: 30 x 4
#>     year site  name     value
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#>  1  2019 A     square       3
#>  2  2019 A     triangle     9
#>  3  2019 A     circle       5
#>  4  2019 A     square       5
#>  5  2019 A     triangle    NA
#>  6  2019 A     circle      34
#>  7  2019 B     square       0
#>  8  2019 B     triangle     0
#>  9  2019 B     circle      69
#> 10  2019 B     square      NA
#> # … with 20 more rows
```